# How do we know that vaccum is devoid of matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vacuum

According to Wikipedia:-

> Vacuum is a state with no matter particles (hence the name), and no photons.

How do we know that a part of space is devoid of matter?I basically want to ask how do we know that a part of space doesn't contain matter?What mechanisms do we use?How is it possible to know that there is no matter or absolute vaccum?

Comment: "Vacuum" is _defined_ as space containing no matter. If your question actually is about deep, inter-galactic space, then there is no _true_ vacuum anywhere that we know of. Any place you look, you will always find at least a few hydrogen atoms flying around in each cubic meter even if you don't find anything else. You probably could try asking on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ if you want to know how we know what's out there.

Comment: One comment that might be relevant here: the state probed as a vacuum by inertial observers is seem, by uniformly accelerated observers, as a thermal bath at temperature proportional to the acceleration (which ends up being very small because of the combination of constants multiplying the acceleration). This is the Unruh effect and it has to do with the fact that the inertial observer and the uniformly accelerated one doesn't agree in what each calls "positive frequency". This shows that the idea of "the" vacuum state can be subtle, specially in curved spacetimes.

Comment: No answer is possible until you ask more clearly. Do you mean what measuring device would be sufficient? Do you mean a thought-experiment? Do you mean a definition? And if so, then are you thinking classical physics or quantum field theory? If the latter then do you already know any quantum field theory?